# How do i reset my password

Tags: password

Ok so i tried to reset my password using these instructions

1. Hold shift during start menu to open up the ubuntu menu
2. Hit enter on recovery mode
3. Hit enter on root
   After that this appeared like it was supposed to root@vera-hp-g62-pc: or something like that and i put in the code "passwd" (dont add the apostraphe's) and than my user name 
   Immediatly fallowing that it asked me to enter a new password only problem was that i couldnt type and had to use the "exit" comand (again no apostraphe) 
   P.S. I ignored the fact that the characters werent visible and entered my would be password but an error messege showed up

Answer (score 0):

It is normal behavior for `passwd` to not show your password or even placeholders for characters (as is done in many apps including web browsers) because if someone knew the number of characters in your password it would be significantly faster to brute force.
So just type away then press enter.

Comment: I would agree but i thought of that but after typing it in i recieved an error messege

Comment: and the error message was?